# Rubymotion x Facebook iOS SDK // Install problems // [!] Unable to find a specification for `Facebook-iOS-SDK`

Tags: ios, ruby, sdk, facebook-c#-sdk, rubymotion

After having successfully installed and used the SDK on another computer for a project,
I'm struggling to make it works on another station, getting the following error :

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `Facebook-iOS-SDK`.
```

The version of the SDK is v3.5.1.

With the following rakefile :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project'
require 'bundler'
require 'motion-cocoapods'
Bundler.require

Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  app.name = 'FacebookApp'
  app.frameworks    = ["UIKit", "Foundation", 'AdSupport', 'Accounts', 'Social']
  app.weak_frameworks += %w{ AdSupport Accounts Social }
  app.pods do
    pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
  end
  app.device_family          = :iphone
  app.interface_orientations = [:portrait]
  app.info_plist['FacebookAppID'] = 'xxx'
  app.info_plist['URL types'] = { 'URL Schemes' => 'fb://profile/xxx'}
  app.identifier = 'xxx'
end
```

And the following Gemfile :

```
# A sample Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "motion-cocoapods", "1.3.0.rc1"
gem "cocoapods"
gem 'bubble-wrap'
```

Would there be something that is to add (environments paths, another sdk version to install… whatever) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ pod install --force
```

solved it. Some cache problem or something obviously.

**EDIT**

Usually, those kind of problems are solved with a `rake clean:all`, and a reinstall of it all (`bundle install && rake pod:install`)

Comment: Where did you type this command? It says: '[!] No `Podfile' found in the current working directory'

Comment: Good question.. I Guess if you have the same setup, it should do the thing. Reading again my code, seems to me that I have cocoapods specified in the gemfile and in the rake file, which might not useful

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it turns out I had already `pod install`'d in that dir.  This can be checked by simply typing `pod` with no args.

For the pod n00bz like me, you will need to `pod init` to generate the podfile (this step is not in the [Getting Started docs](http://cocoapods.org/) I am following at the moment).

Comment: I think you mean `pod setup` or possibly `bundle exec pod setup`

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had moved my repository to a new computer, and had not yet run this:

```
bundle exec pod setup
```

Comment: bundle exec LOL setup ?

Comment: Yeah, probably didn't need that, did I? It's definitely habit for me to run most everything in the context of my environment.

Comment: I might not get your sense of humor but you seem to go further